# Synchronously launch app on a group of local Windows machines, with easy GUI to launch/kill/manage

Tags: windows, remote-control

I'm looking for a easy method to launch specific applications on a group of windows clients. The clients will mostly be backpack PCs, with only a VR headset attached. I'd like to have an operator with a tablet, or web interface (something like a media player) to select an group of clients, and then be able to start one of a select set  applications on all clients simultaneously. Any currently running app would be stopped, and the new app would start. Basic PC management would be a plus to, like On/Off/Reboot/Kill running app. Being able to remotely manage the application list would also be nice.  Operator console/tablet, and clients would all be on the same local network.

I've found psexec, which might work if I build an interface around it,  but I'd like to find something off the shelf if possible.